# Como deleto a imagem antes do upload da mesma usando Multer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

Estou com uma certa dificuldade no Javascript e NodeJs. Sou nova neles. Fiz um aplicativo em React Native e a pessoa pode optar em deletar a imagem do perfil dela. Também tem imagens na parte de anúncios. Eu gostaria de deletar as imagens antes do upload das novas, pois o usuário pode escolher em não usar imagens mais futuramente. Eu estou usando o Multer para os uploads e o fs.unlink para deletar as imagens. Mas eu não estou sabendo onde encaixar o fs.unlink para deleta-las antes, se é dentro do próprio multer ou tenho que criar um middleware, não faço idéia...

```js
const deleteFile = (filePath) => {
fs.unlink(filePath, (error) => {
  if (!error) {
    console.log(false);
  } else {
    console.log('Erro ao deletar arquivo.');
  }
})};

const StoragePerfil = multer.diskStorage({
        destination(req, file, callback) {
            callback(null, './assets/upload/perfil');
        },
        filename: (req, file, callback) => {
            callback(null, `${file.originalname}`)
        },
        });
const uploadPerfil = multer({ storage: StoragePerfil });


app.put('/user/perfil/:id_user', authMiddleware.checkAuth, uploadPerfil.array('photo', 3), perfilController.updatePerfil);
```

Answer (score 1):

Já consegui resolver. Eu verifico se existe ou não a imagem e coloquei na função de update.

```js
const deleteFile = (filePath) => {
fs.unlink(filePath, (error) => {
  if (!error) {
    console.log(false);
  } else {
    console.log('Erro ao deletar arquivo.');
  }
})};


if (typeof req.body.photo === undefined) {         
   funcao.deleteFile(pathfile);       
}
```

Obrigada.